# Python script to check if user input value exists in dataframe

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, pymysql

I am writing a python script, where I use pymysql to connect to my MYSQL database and execute a query.

```
#sql query to get a list of country codes with country names    
query = ("SELECT MCC as 'MCC',Name as 'Name' FROM Enum.Country")
    cursor.execute(query)
    a = cursor.fetchall()
    print(a)
 #convert a to dataframe   
    df = pd.DataFrame(list(a),columns=["MCC","Name"])
    print(df)
#get the user input  
   user_input2 = raw_input("From the list, please enter the mcc of the country you want to create the service for:")
```

My data frame looks like:

```
     MCC                    Name
0    276                 Albania
1    603                 Algeria
2      0           All Countries
3    213                 Andorra
4    631                  Angola
5    722      Argentine Republic
6    283                 Armenia
7    505               Australia
8    232                 Austria
9    400              Azerbaijan
```

How can I check if the user_input2 is present in the dataframe df?
Thanks In advance.

Comment: you want to check in which column?

Comment: try `df.MCC.isin([user_input2])`

Comment: @Dark: It is showing me value error:The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Comment: @pyd: I want to check in MCC column

Comment: @AshwathaRavi cast your raw input to `int` and then try

Comment: @Dark Got it ! thanks:) I used input instead of raw_input

Answer (score 1):

you can check like this,

```
 df.MCC.isin([user_input2]).any()
```

Comment: I entered a valid MCC. But still, it is showing doesnt exist.

Comment: I am getting True for `df.MCC.isin([276]).any()`